# Element Type Mismatch

Tags: java

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Arrays;
 
public class Main{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader reader = null; 
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    try{
      reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Numbers.txt"));
      String currentLine = reader.readLine();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("ERROR: WRONG FILE " + e.toString());
    }
    String currentLine = reader.readLine();
    while (currentLine != null){
      lines.add(currentLine);
      currentLine = reader.readLine();
    Collections.sort(lines);
    ArrayList[] linesSorted = lines.toArray(new ArrayList[lines.size()]);
    System.out.println("Sorted Array: " + Arrays.toString(linesSorted));
    }
  }
}
```

When I enter this Code, which is meant to Read a list of Words from another File, Turn it into an Array, and then Sort said Array, an Error Message Pops up saying

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException: arraycopy: element type mismatch: can not cast one of the elements of java.lang.Object[] to the type of the destination array, java.util.ArrayList
    at java.base/java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.toArray(ArrayList.java:433)
    at Main.main(Main.java:24)
```

I'm not too sure what this Error Message Means, or how I can fix it. Help! I am very new to Computer coding, so my knowledge about the topic is not great.

Answer (score -1):

You have:

```
ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
```

And you do:

```
ArrayList[] linesSorted = lines.toArray(new ArrayList[lines.size()]);
```

The expected type of array for `toArray()` is either:

- `toArray(new String[0]);`
- `toArray(new Object[0]);`

You can not use `new ArrayList[lines.size()]` because the `ArrayList` is storing `String` (array type should be `String[]`) and you pass a `ArrayList[]`.

The compiler could probably have tell you about this either as a warning, either as an error.